# Azure Identity and Key Vault: How to use managed identities to authenticate?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to use the Azure Identity package to access Key Vault secrets. I am using AzureML and it has its own system assigned managed identity ("Identity" in the left-hand blade).

This system assigned managed identity yields me an Object (principal) ID. It also allows me to set Azure role assignments. This managed identity is a: (1) contributor, (2) administrator, and (3) key vaults secret user for the key vault service I want to use with my secrets.

Inside AzureML, on a Python notebook, if I run:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

# load key vault data
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url="--KV URL--", credential=credential)
secret_client.get_secret("secret-i-want")
```

```
# fails
EnvironmentCredential.get_token failed: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
```

Fair enough, it tells me to basically create a service principal and put its details into the environment. But, I don't want to. I want to use the Managed Identity which is apparently best in class for security because I am not storing secrets anywhere.

Looking through documentation, there exists a way to allegedly use the Managed Identity, but I cannot make it work. https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-identity/1.6.0/azure.identity.html#azure.identity.ManagedIdentityCredential

I am uncertain how to get a client ID for AzureML or its managed identity.

```
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
credential2 = ManagedIdentityCredential(identity_config={"object_id": "principal-id-for-aml-managed-identity"})
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url="--KV URL--", credential=credential2)
# hangs with no error
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tested in my environment.

You can use AzureCliCrendential instead of ManagedIdentityCredential.

In the terminal, login using below  command to login using System Assigned Identiy

```
az login --identity
```

Now, use the below pyhton notebook script :

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

managed_identity = AzureCliCredential()
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://radapakv.vault.azure.net/", credential=managed_identity)
value = secret_client.get_secret("test")
```

Comment: Thanks but this will be of little help if you want to trigger pipeline runs.

Comment: Can you try with ManagedIdentityCredential instead of AzureCliCredential